# convert a string to a cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a column vector of integers and I want to convert it into cell in matlab. The following is the code. But it did not output what I expected.

```
nodes = [10; 21; 44];
nodes = num2str(nodes)
nodes = num2cell(nodes)

nodes =

10
21
44


nodes = 

    '1'    '0'
    '2'    '1'
    '4'    '4'
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Do you want strings in the cells or numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third line's argument, `nodes` is a string and not a number anymore.
Therefore you can use the `cellstr`-function to convert the string-array to a cell-array of strings.

```
nodes = [10; 21; 44];
nodes = num2str(nodes)
nodes = cellstr(nodes)
```

*This outputs:*

```
nodes =
10
21
44

nodes = 
    '10'
    '21'
    '44'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `arrayfun` (i.e. a wrapper for a for-loop):

```
arrayfun(@num2str, nodes, 'uni', 0)
```

or if you want numbers in the cells (not strings) then it's just

```
num2cell(nodes)
```

i.e. without the `num2str`